# How can i get router devices on my network programmatically?

Tags: networking, router

I've been searching ways to get router devices list on my network and I'm asking for your help. I've found few protocols such as IRDP, LLDP, CDP, MNDP which i can might try however, they mixed my mind completely.

To sum up, I have a network which contains many router devices from different manufacturers.I want to get them programmaticaly by sending a request over network. Which request should i send ?

Comment: There is always the IPv4 `All Routers on this Subnet` multicast group and the IPv6 `All Routers Address` multicast group. Routers should join the router multicast group of the IP for which it is routing. Remember that routers are just hosts on the network that know how to reach other networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your network has Mikrotik device you can discover all router devices on network by sending UDP broadcast request over network on port 5678 and should listen 5678 to get response.
To invoke MNDP protocol on Mikrotik device you should send few udp packets.
For more detail visit :
https://hadler.me/cc/mikrotik-neighbor-discovery-mndp/

Although I didn't try it by myself, here are few other ways that i find to get them:

- CDP request ( For cisco device - I'm not sure if its work for TP-Link device )
- LLDP request
- SNMP request